# ec2 public-hostname on instance reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to get the public-hostname of an instance to launch the service on reboot. When I use 'ec2-metadata', I don't get the info when I place the call at @reboot in crontab. So what is the way I should solve the problem in question?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait a bit before the hostname becomes available after reboot. So either run the  ec2-metadata command later in the bootup sequence after network interfaces have stabilised, or sleep until it returns something useful

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is not to use cron, but rather place the script in /etc/profile.d

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Ubuntu for OS.

I would try hooking it into the network-manager start event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script with this command

```
publicdns=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
```

That will store your ec2's public hostname inside the $publicdns variable.  Then you can also have the script run whatever commands you need run.  Schedule the script to run @reboot with cron.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, type this to get the public ip address

```
curl ifconfig.me
```